# SQL create login

Tags: sql

hello every one I am trying to crate a login with windows authentication and I write the following query on my Query tab

create login yaya from windows

and I get the following error message

'yaya' is not a valid windowsNT name. Give the compelete name:.

Comment: what does this have to do with facebook?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: and what version of windows?

Comment: You might need to add the network name. I.e. MyDomain\yaya

Comment: I am using SQL 2014 on windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the domain name:

```
CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<login_name>] FROM WINDOWS;
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx